# seaborn plots empty white plane

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

When plotting a CSV with pandas the values below with seaborn:

```
 value       date       
0.296776    2016-07-01
0.273482    2016-08-01
0.207982    2016-09-01
0.176148    2016-10-01
0.124666    2016-11-01
0.072311    2016-12-01
0.042762    2017-01-01
0.043232    2017-02-01
0.083472    2017-03-01
```

`sns.tsplot(time="date", value="value", data=df)`

I only get an empty white plane - what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing with [`.tsplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html) is that it's meant to plot timeseries with representation of uncertainty,  so if you are not providing to the function a field in the DataFrame that identifies the sampling unit, it's not going to work.

To bypass this without going through the trouble of modifying your `.csv` dataset, you should not use the `data` argument:

```
>>> sns.tsplot(df['value'],time=df['date'])
<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x07DA7A30>
>>> sns.plt.show()
```

[image]